# In SQL Server 2008 how can I query for tables with foreign key references to a specific table column?

Tags: sql, sql-server

In MSSQL 2008 how can I query for tables with foreign key references to a specific table column?

Let's say I have a table called Audit with an int column called 'ID".
How can I find all the tables in my database that have a foreign key to Audit.ID ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
SELECT
K_Table = FK.TABLE_NAME,
FK_Column = CU.COLUMN_NAME,
PK_Table = PK.TABLE_NAME,
PK_Column = PT.COLUMN_NAME,
Constraint_Name = C.CONSTRAINT_NAME
FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.REFERENTIAL_CONSTRAINTS C
INNER JOIN INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLE_CONSTRAINTS FK ON C.CONSTRAINT_NAME = FK.CONSTRAINT_NAME
INNER JOIN INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLE_CONSTRAINTS PK ON C.UNIQUE_CONSTRAINT_NAME = PK.CONSTRAINT_NAME
INNER JOIN INFORMATION_SCHEMA.KEY_COLUMN_USAGE CU ON C.CONSTRAINT_NAME = CU.CONSTRAINT_NAME
INNER JOIN (
SELECT i1.TABLE_NAME, i2.COLUMN_NAME
FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLE_CONSTRAINTS i1
INNER JOIN INFORMATION_SCHEMA.KEY_COLUMN_USAGE i2 ON i1.CONSTRAINT_NAME = i2.CONSTRAINT_NAME
WHERE i1.CONSTRAINT_TYPE = 'PRIMARY KEY'
) PT ON PT.TABLE_NAME = PK.TABLE_NAME
---- optional:
ORDER BY
1,2,3,4
WHERE PK.TABLE_NAME='something'WHERE FK.TABLE_NAME='something'
WHERE PK.TABLE_NAME IN ('one_thing', 'another')
WHERE FK.TABLE_NAME IN ('one_thing', 'another')
```

Comment: yikes -- I will be saving this one.

Comment: This answer was copied and pasted from here: http://blog.sqlauthority.com/2006/11/01/sql-server-query-to-display-foreign-key-relationships-and-name-of-the-constraint-for-each-table-in-database/

We really ought to credit our sources.

Comment: When I next post an answer for someone...if I fail to credit the original source.  I have no problem with the help nazi coming back and letting me know that I really didn't help because, I should of credited the solution.  Sheesh.

Answer (score 1):

```
declare @keys table
( 
    ForeignKey varchar(100),
    TableName varchar(100),
    ColumnName varchar(100),
    ReferenceTableName varchar(100),
    ReferenceColumnName varchar(100)
)
insert @keys
SELECT f.name AS ForeignKey,
TableName = OBJECT_NAME(f.parent_object_id),
ColumnName = COL_NAME(fc.parent_object_id,
fc.parent_column_id),
OBJECT_NAME (f.referenced_object_id) AS ReferenceTableName,
COL_NAME(fc.referenced_object_id,
fc.referenced_column_id) AS ReferenceColumnName
FROM sys.foreign_keys AS f
INNER JOIN sys.foreign_key_columns AS fc
ON f.OBJECT_ID = fc.constraint_object_id

select * from @Keys where TableName='X' and ColumnName='Y'
```